# Scrollview component issue

Tags: android, scrollview

I am developing a chat application in andriod. In that I have a contact list, where I have online and offline users. I have put a header label as a textView and added text 'Online Users' and below that I have put a listview which holds online users. Below that I placed another textview with text 'Offline Users'. Below that I have placed another list view that holds offline users. And my requirement is that, I need to scroll the all the four as a component, not the online listview alone and offline listview alone.

Can I place a Vertical scrollview as parent and all these four components inside it to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You can, but I think it's a bad idea. Even Google does not recommend creating nested scrollable containers. The reason is simple - it's hard to tell how such layout should behave like. ListViews and ScrollViews have their own ways of dealing with touches, trackballs and keys. Both pretty agressively intercept touch events and cache/reuse their children.

I would recommend using ExpandableListView with expanded groups. Place your lists as group children. Such container will reuse and cache views, allow to scroll everything with one gesture and in general will work much more intuitive. I guess using simple ListView and 3 view types would do the trick as well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I would not agree. The author is asking about an idea to place list view inside scroll view and I claim that it's bad idea. Nesting scrollable containers is not recomended by Google and the reason is simple - there's no easy way to tell, what such layout should behave like. I'm not trying to insult anybody nor I need any clarification. I''ll edit my answer to make it more informative.

Comment: @Zielony How can I add a listview as a child of an Expandable listview. Can you please explain with an example?

Comment: Adapter for ExpandableListGroup can return two types of rows. One of them is group header and the second one is group child. I'm assuming you already have simple adapters for both of your lists (online and offline). Now you have to implement adapter for ExpadableListView (ELV), which takes data for both lists and returns simple list rows as child rows for ELV. Don't add ListView as a child - rather merge your adapters and return ListView rows as child rows. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html

Answer (score 1):

The feature you're looking for is ListView's viewTypes.

Return the number of different views from getViewTypeCount() and 0..n-1 from getViewType() to tell ListView that there are that many different types of view in the adapter.

```
private static final int TYPE_TITLE = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ONLINE = 1;
private static final int TYPE_OFFLINE = 2;

public int getViewTypeCount(){
    return 3;
}

public int getViewType(){
    if(i == 0 || i == onlineUsers.size() + 1){
        return TYPE_TITLE;
    }else if (i < onlineUsers.size() + 1){
        return TYPE_ONLINE;
    }else{
        return TYPE_OFFLINE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No don't do that. If you do so then the listview cant work as desired. Instead use header and footer feature for the first listview. Now you can scroll as an entire view without using a scrollview.

EDIT :

This is a rough example to indicate how you can put header and footer in your case.

You can have seperate xml files for header and footer say,

header.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#AAFFDD" >
    <Textview...>
    </LinearLayout>
```

footer.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#AAFFDD" >

    <Textview.../>
     <Listview 
      android:id="@+id/listview2 ../>
</LinearLayout>
```

Your first Listview will be like this in seperate layout i.e main layout,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Listview
        android:id="@+id/listview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.97"
        android:background="@color/main_gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In java code initialize gridview as,

```
Listview listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
```

Now Attach header and footer to this view,

```
// Attaches footer to ListView 
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
gridview.addHeaderView(headerView);

// Attaches footer to ListView 
LinearLayout footerView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.footer, null);
gridview.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Comment: How can I do that by adding header and footer? Can u please explain?

Comment: I have edited the answer above. Hope it works for you.